# Avoid passing preset variables to function in PHP

Tags: php, function, variables

I'd like to make my life easier avoiding to pass some preset variables to a function in PHP.

For example, this works:

```
function test1($var2,$var3,$var1=1){
    return '$var1='.$var1.'+$var2='.$var2.'+$var3'.$var3;
}
echo test1($var2=2,$var3=3);
#$var1=1+$var2=2+$var33
```

But this doesn't (without the warnings):

```
function test($var1=1,$var2,$var3){
    return '$var1='.$var1.'+$var2='.$var2.'+$var3'.$var3;
}
echo test($var2=2,$var3=3);
#Warning: Missing argument 3 for test(), called in /var/www/atpc.info/f/f/m/t.php on line 6 and defined in /var/www/atpc.info/f/f/m/t.php on line 3
#Notice: Undefined variable: var3 in /var/www/atpc.info/f/f/m/t.php on line 4 
#$var1=2+$var2=3+$var3
```

Maybe the only way to make this to happen is always to put to the end of the line the preset variables. Is it?

Thanks for any light.

Comment: what I do when I need something like this is to pass an associative array with the options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default values need to come after any non-default values as shown in example 5 [on the function arguments page at PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php).

Answer (score 2):

Oy... that is **not** how you pass variables in PHP....

To send variables:

```
function test($var1=1,$var2=1,$var3=1){ //default 1, 1, 1
    return '$var1='.$var1.'+$var2='.$var2.'+$var3'.$var3;
}
echo test(2,3); //only sent for var1 and 2
echo test(null, 2, 3); //only sent for var2 and 3    
echo test(); //default for all
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to examine `variable function arguments in PHP`.

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales, this is obviously a search query. You should be smart enough to copy it to the clipboard and paste into your favourite search engine. A _learn_ answer is always better than a _solve_ answer.

Comment: well, not that obvious to me, 'search' would do, 'examine' didn't give any clue. I love both learn answer, and solve answer, both the solution and the explanation...
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You might make your life easier, but it might result in sloppy code where at some points you SHOULD be passing a parameter and you forget but the code didn't throw any errors. That's my take.